# How to rerender value of child from HOC

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-props, higher-order-components

I want to have a button submiting to stripe a specific quantity, based on an input that can be changed by typing or clicking an increment/decrease button. I have the increment/decrease functions on an higher order component but i am unable to submit it to the button of stripe (child from my understanding)

Relevant code below:

### withCheckout (HOC):

```
import React from "react"

const UpdatedComponent = (OriginalComponent) => {
    class NewComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                count: 1 
            }
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        }


        increment = () => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return { count: prevState.count + 1}
            })
        }

        decrease = () => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return { count: prevState.count - 1 }
            })
        }


        handleChange(event) {
            this.setState({
                count: parseInt(event.target.value)
            });
        }

        render() {
            return <OriginalComponent count={this.state.count} increment={this.increment} decrease={this.decrease} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        }
    }
    return NewComponent
}

export default UpdatedComponent
```

### Checkout:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import UpdatedComponent from "./withCheckout"

const buttonStyles = {
  fontSize: "13px",
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "#000",
  padding: "12px 60px",
  boxShadow: "2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
  backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 178, 56)",
  borderRadius: "6px",
  letterSpacing: "0.2ch",
  display: "block",
  margin: "1.5em auto 1.5em auto",

}

const buttonDisabledStyles = {
  opacity: "0.5",
  cursor: "not-allowed",
}

let stripePromise
const getStripe = () => {
  if (!stripePromise) {
      stripePromise = loadStripe("KEY_HERE")
  }
  return stripePromise
}

const Checkout = props => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const redirectToCheckout = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

    const stripe = await getStripe()
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      mode: "payment",
      lineItems: [{ price: "PRICE_ID_HERE", quantity: props.count }],
      successUrl: `http://localhost:8000/page-2/`,
      cancelUrl: `http://localhost:8000/`,
      shippingAddressCollection: {
        allowedCountries: ['PT'],
  }
    })

    if (error) {
      console.warn("Error:", error)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <button
      disabled={loading}
      style={
        loading ? { ...buttonStyles, ...buttonDisabledStyles } : buttonStyles
      }
      onClick={redirectToCheckout}
    >
          Comprar {props.count}
    </button>
  )
}

export default UpdatedComponent(Checkout)
```

Example:
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jCf0.png)

When I change the input to 7, I expect the button text to be "Comprar 7" and I expect to submit quantity: 7 in the striperedirect function. I think the problem has to do with the way props are set, as my Counter is working well the props were passed as `const {count} = this.props`. Should I add the Counter.js code as well?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. You mention not being able to do what you want, but you haven't included an error. The code you provided seems to deal with styles and Stripe, but they don't seem germane to the problem you described. Can you please edit your question to focus on the question or problem you have?

Comment: My question is 'how can I have the quantity of stripe be equal  to the count value?'. It always submits quantity: 1, despite the value I have on the inputbox. Is there a way to share 'working' code without the keys? I dont get an error, it simply does not work. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the quantity submitted to Stripe is passed to `Checkout` as `props.count`, but you haven't shared where you're rendering `<Checkout count={…} />`.

Comment: I might have this wrong then. I want to submite the value of the input field, not the other way around. See this https://imgur.com/7uFXoDg